# Moving focus from UITextfield after entering 2 characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The next code will work only when the user will enter the third character. I want the focus to move TextField when the user enters the second character but still keep the first 2 characters in the first TextField. if I'll try something like`newString.length < 2` , when entering 2 characters in a row I'll get the first character in the first `UITextField` and the second character in the second `UITextField`.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if (newString.length <= 2 )
    {

        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        NSInteger nextTag;
        nextTag = textField.tag + 1;

        UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
        if (nextResponder) {
            [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];            
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: have you tried with `newString.length <= 1` ?

Comment: Your missing a return statement in your `else`. Try adding `return YES` in there.

Comment: @zbMax <= will result this: Entering 23 will give me: first textfield=2 , second textfield = 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive this should work:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if(newString.length == 2)
    {
        UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:textField.tag + 1];

        if (nextResponder) {
            [nextResponder performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
        }
        else {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }

    return newString.length <= 2;
}
```

Please try it and tell me if it works. If not please tell me a bit more about your setup and I will try to set up a view like yours and it will be easier for me to try solutions.

Ok, **EDIT** The above works. It is not very beautiful but it does the job. It is sad that apple would not add a method for didChangeCharactersInRange which would be much more appropriate for this.

**EDIT** Edited according to Sha's findings 0.1 instead of 0 in the timer interval

**EDIT** Changed according to Mike's suggestion

Comment: It won't work. Entering 23 will result: first textfield=2 , second textfield = 3. You can create a simple view with 3 UITextFields with tags 1 2 3 4.

Comment: wasn't it working with the code before edit and with `newString.length == 3` ?

Comment: The above works but my major issue with it is the brief millisecond that shows the the current `UITextField` content in the next UITextField. I can figure out why this is happening. I don't mind if the code is not that beautiful but the above glitch catches the eye.  EDIT: I found an easy fix for the above. Changing the scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval to 0.1 did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Even better would be: `[nextResponder performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0]`.

Comment: @MikePollard You'll still need to 0.1 your `afterDelay` to avoid the next UITextfield glitch annoyance.